# passing a function for decorator

Tags: python

Need a help on this.

Have a file with_class.py that holds implementation of decorator on classes. The function is being called from another file use_class.py.

with_class.py

```
def __init__(self,f):
     self.f = f 
def __call__(self,x): 
     self.f(x) 

@decorate
def foo(x): 
    print "inside foo" , x
```

use_class.py

```
import with_class
a = with_class.foo(x)
```

It works fine. 
Now if i want to pass a function in place of x.
I have function defined in with_class.py and in the use_class.py I want to pass to "a = with_class.foo(with_class.decorate.disp()) " . 
disp() is the function defined inside the class. The code above now looks like:

with_class.py

```
class decorate: 
       def __init__(self,f): 
           self.f = f 
       def __call__(self,g):
           self.f(g) 

      def disp(self):
          print "inside the display"

@decorate 
def foo(fn): 
    print "inside foo"
    fn()
```

use_class.py

```
import with_class
a = with_class.foo(with_class.decorate.disp())
```

I am getting error

```
"**TypeError: unbound method disp() must be called with decorate instance as first argument**".
```

Can someone please help me to find where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to foo must be a function.  This code

```
with_class.foo(with_class.decorate.disp())
```

is the exact equivalent of

```
x = with_class.decorate.disp()
with_class.foo(x)
```

The error occurs in the first line when you call `with_class.decorate.disp()`, since `disp` is an instance method and can only be called on an *instance* of `decorate`. You don't want to call `disp`; you want to pass it to foo as an argument.  Something like this:

```
class decorate: 
    def __init__(self,f):
        print("decorate constructor")
        self.f = f 
    def __call__(self,g):
        print("Call", g)
        self.f(g)
        print("Call ended")
    @staticmethod
    def disp():
        print("inside the display")

@decorate 
def foo(fn): 
    print("inside foo")
    fn()

print("About to foo")
foo(decorate.disp)
```

Running this (Python3) gives:

```
decorate constructor
About to foo
Call <function decorate.disp at 0x02A2D108>
inside foo
inside the display
Call ended
```

Comment: ...I tried with the code as above and it worked fine. But I tried using another file "use_class.py" in which :  import with_class

Comment: import with_class                                                                         with_class.foo(decorate.disp)                                               it's failing with error......NameError:  name 'decorate' is not defined .

Comment: If you define `decorate` in another file named with_class, then you need to reference it as `with_class.decorate` or else do `from with_class import decorate`.  That's how Python works and is not specifically related to decorators.